# Selenium grid 4 with SSL - Setup works but unable to create driver from code

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, openssl, selenium-grid

I am using the latest Selenium 4 alpha jar and its need feature to setup grid with SSL. The grid is ready and I can see that the status is showing grid is ready.

The code I have is running in Selenium 3.5.3 and I am getting the below error in the new RemoteWebDriver statement.

```
PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

I have added the .pem file to all possible cacerts file in my hub machine. Not sure how to proceed with solving this issue.

Comment: You need to download the root certificate of the website which you are trying to access over SSL. And then you need to add it into JVM cacerts.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is the root certificate different from the one used to set up the hub ? If yes, then do you know from where I can get it ? I've set up the hub in Linux machine..

Comment: For me, the simplest way to download any root certificate is to just open that website in chrome and then click on security icon and then click on certificate and save it. https://i.stack.imgur.com/mQNKY.png

Comment: Thank you.. will try this..